# What's a good way of converting 1 or 0 to a boolean value?

Tags: .net

I have a database with where boolean values are stored as bits (1 for true, 0 for false). What's the best way of converting these into .Net boolean values from a DataRow? Convert.ToBoolean doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why doesn't Convert.ToBoolean work? It has worked for me for years.

Comment: Always returns false. Discovered that if I .ToString the row value it works fine though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data type in the database is `bit`, then you don't have to do any conversion at all. The database driver automatically reads the values as booleans, all you have to do is to unbox the value:

```
bool value = (bool)row["field"];
```

Comment: This is easily the most sensible solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool flag = (row[0]["Flag"] != DBNull.Value) ? (bool)row[0]["Flag"] : false;
```

Comment: If the db value is nullable shouldn't you then be using: bool? flag = (row[0]["Flag"] != DBNull.Value) ? (bool)row[0]["Flag"] : null; instead?

Comment: your code will not work  JohannesH, you will get compile error

Comment: @JohannesH: It is an option. Depends how nulls are handled in the application.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool flag = (row[0]["Flag"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToBoolean(row[0]["Flag"]) : false
```

should work. However you may want to think about how to treat the NULL value case as here it is deemed to be set to false which you may or not wish to be the case.